# How to use the FTP to upload a small file or an image in android studio using Kotlin

Tags: ftp, kotlin

I am trying to create an app that needs to upload some images and text files to my server which supports FTP. I am from a python background and have used FTP a lot in the past but I am pretty confused while using it in Kotlin any help will be appreciated.

Comment: FTP is an old, unsafe and inperformant protocol, especially because it opens a new port for every file transfer. Consider using alternatives like SFTP (not to be confused with FTPS)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but my server only supports FTP (its kind of a headache )and I want to use it so I am kinda stuck with FTP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **ftp4j** library by download [ftp4j-1.7.2.jar](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/download.php).

Here is sample code in kotlin.

```
try {
    val mFtpClient = FTPClient()
    mFtpClient.connect("hots", PORT)
    mFtpClient.login("user", "password")
    mFtpClient.type = FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY
    mFtpClient.changeDirectory("/directory_path/")

    mFtpClient.upload(File("file_path"))
    mFtpClient.disconnect(true)

} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: @ZararYounis That code should not produce any syntax errors, did you add the library to your gradle dependencies?

Comment: yeah I corrected it and its working now thanks but I ended up using apache commons net I will upload the code soon

Comment: there is this tho, but the app just closes ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424402/how-bypass-networkonmainthreadexception-on-kotlin

Comment: Found this in my google search. Please note that ftp4j looks unmaintained. The last version 1.7.3 on GitHub is from 2015 and there hasn't been any activity since. I wouldn't recommend using outdated libraries.